# Same Content is getting displayed in every page?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am working on jsPDF with multiple page. I am not being able to add header and footer to my page and the content displayed is same in every page.

Can anybody help me what mistake I did?

```
generatePDF() {
    let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

    let content = this.finalContent;

    let pageHeight = 295;

    let image = content["image"];
    let width = content["width"];
    let height = content["height"];

    let imgHeight = height;

    let heightLeft = imgHeight;
    let position = 0;

    doc.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 10, 30, width, height);

    heightLeft -= pageHeight;

    while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        doc.addPage();
        doc.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 10, position, width, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
    }
    doc.save("test.pdf");
}
```

Comment: remove `doc.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 10, position, width, imgHeight);` from the loop, though the logic looks like you want multiple pages but you only have one thing to add. :/ image is not changing so it will repeat

Comment: @LawrenceCherone my image consist of table with 100 rows. I did doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, position + 30, imgWidth, imgHeight); now content is ok but I am not being able to add footer

Comment: Note image will be `let image = content["image"];` line, if you have another image set outside, you should not call it image

Comment: @LawrenceCherone How can I add footer?